# How to add WP theme css in a javascript for innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

Here is my code:

```js
if (document.getElementById('business').checked) {
  document.getElementById('register[category]').innerHTML= '<span class="tg-select"><option value="">Select Category</option> <option value="1391">Hospital</option><option value="1393">Clinic</option></span>';
}
```

```html
<select name="register[category]" id="register[category]" class="sp-category">
</select>
```

this doesn't apply any css to the drop down menu. Please guide

Comment: Hi is the script in a document ready or onload?

Comment: where is the `#business` element?

Comment: Its onclick() event for a radio button, there are two options (business & professional) and when someone choose the radio button they get different drop downs. but the drop down does not have any style I want to apply theme css.